# Python - pause until 1 minute passes to run the code again

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to run code specifically if the day of the week is a Monday and if the hour is 4pm. I've created a weekday array that starts on "Monday", which passes the first check, however I'm testing to see if when the hour isn't 4pm, then it should pause for another minute, then continue the loop. However it just pauses at the pause until and doesn't continue.

My assumption was that even though I'm passing the pause.until(datetime()) the day/time variable, it would still continue the moment the clock hits the next minute.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import discord
import os
from keepalive import keep_alive
import calendar
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pytz
import pause

while True:
  #get todays date into an array and convert to value variables
  today = date.today().isoformat()
  year = today[0:4]
  month = today[5:7]
  day = today[8:10]
  #need to format the string into hour minute second
  hour = datetime_London.strftime("%H")
  minute = datetime_London.strftime("%M")
  second = datetime_London.strftime("%S")


  #get the current time from pytz module 
  tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
  datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)

  #convert strings to int's for calendar.weekday function
  year = int(year)
  month = int(month)
  day = int(day)
  hour = int(datetime_London.strftime("%H"))
  minute = int(datetime_London.strftime("%M"))
  second = int(datetime_London.strftime("%S"))

  #turn current date into the weekday
  weekday = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
  
  if weekday != 0:
    pause.until(datetime(year,month,day + 1))
  elif weekday == 0:
      if hour != 16:
        print("datetime before pause: ", datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute, second))
        pause.until(datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute + 1, second))
        print("datetime after pause: ", datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute, second))
```

Comment: What is your script is doing? Maybe better to create some kind of cron job or use windows scheduling if on windows?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to create a Discord bot that will send a message to a Discord Client/Server/Channel every Monday at 4pm. I'm new to Python and was slowly working up to it. I might have to have a look at cron as I've seen it mentioned before, but didn't understand it too well at first. I assumed it might be possible all in one script doing it this way.

Comment: In description you mentioned that it should pause for another minute, but in code you pause for another day, not for minute

Comment: Hi @theonepatriot, welcome to SO! Could you post a complete minimal working example, including imports? In particular, I'm wondering where `pause.until()` is from.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I'm looking at the elif in the loop - as today is a Monday it's passing the first check without an issue.

Comment: Try using `pause.minutes(1)` instead.

Comment: @balu Thanks for the welcome! I've updated the question to show the imports. The import is simply called pause :)

Comment: `pause.minutes(1)` is a good call since I don't think `pause.until()` takes the timezone into account and London is on daylight saving time right now.

Comment: @ProblemsLoop Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'll amend the first check of the if statement too. Many thanks!

Comment: I recommend you change your script behavior. If you pausing - the script is in your PC memory and if something goes wrong you need to run the script manually. Use scheduling of your operating system! Don't forget about logging everything that is going on in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ProblemsLoop 's suggestion worked out - I've changed the pause.until to a pause.minutes(1) and it started running the code again after a minute had passed.

```
  if weekday != 0:
    pause.days(1)
  elif weekday == 0:
      if hour != 16:
        print("datetime before pause: ", datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute, second))
        pause.minutes(1)
        print("datetime after pause: ", datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute, second))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```py
import time
time.sleep(specify seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `pause.until(...)` to `pause.minutes(1)` makes your code a lot cleaner and safer. As to why it wasn't working with the new datetime object, it may be due to you not passing the tzinfo. If you do need to make a new datetime object, you just need to pass it.

```
pause.until(datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute + 1, second, tzinfo=tz_London))
```

Some additional notes:

- Many of your statements seem redundant. A [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object has the properties, `year, month, day`, etc. Therefore, you do not need `strftime` just to get specific parts of the object.

```
hour = datetime_London.hour
minute = datetime_London.minute
second = datetime_London.second
```

-You do not need another new datetime object in your print statements, as you already have `datetime_London`

```
print("datetime before pause: ", datetime_London)
print("datetime before pause: ", datetime.now(tz_London))
```

Comment: Ah that's good to know! Thanks - I'll amended the redundant code.